# How to change the icon

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, shiny, icons

kindly help how to change the download icon like this

[image: Expected output]

```
 customDownloadbutton <- function(outputId, label = ""){
              tags$a(id = outputId, class = "btn btn-default shiny-download-link", href = "", 
                     target = "_blank", download = NA, icon("far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"), label)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the string in the icon() call to the desired icon from the [fa library](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/).